# Golang: Getting started - "go" is not recognized as an internal or external command"

Tags: windows, go

Trying to get started with Go but I cant manage to set up the work environnement properly.

Comment: You either have to add c:\go\bin to your path or call go by it's full path.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

EDITED for future reference.

1. You set your 'GOROOT' wrong. Set it to C:\Go\
2. Include C:\Go\bin to your 'Path'

Comment: Already tried that but seems to not work. Should I be calling "go" from a specific directory in the cmd?

Comment: What about 'PATH' it self? Does it include 'C:\Go\bin'? It should.

Comment: **Never** **ever** (except you know what you are doing) set GOROOT. Never. And do not give this advice to anybody.

Comment: Setting "Path" to that made it work. Now when I type go it lists all the commands so I think it works, but when I type "go env", it says "GOPATH entry is relative; must be absolute path: "\\USERS\\William\\Go". Do you know what this means?

Comment: Set it to "C:\Users\William\Go" instead of "%HOMEPATH%\Go

Answer (score 12):

Aside from @Xeph's answer, just make sure if you recently installed Go that you use a fresh terminal/cmd window.

Answer (score 4):

Run command "go env" and check the path for variable "gopath" that's where you should keep your project. Else where if you run go command you will get error "go is not recognized as internal or external command"

Answer (score 2):

here's what made it work for me, assuming you hadnt change anything from a fresh GO install in windows 10.

1. set GOROOT in user variables:  **`C:\Go\`**

   - [GOROOT User Variable screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fNus2.jpg)
2. add path in user variables: **`%USERPROFILE%\Go\bin`**

   - [Add path to User Variables screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/493ZB.jpg)
3. add path in system variables: **`C:\Go\bin`**

   - [Add path to System Variables screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OA0Zz.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

I read various answers as well articles and most effective steps that helped me were :

1. My Computer -> RC -> Properties
2. Advanced System Settings -> Environment Variables
3. [Under System Variables Section -> New -> GOPATH -> Project Location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BU8Ny.png)
4. [Select Path -> New ->path to bin of installed go](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xtmqz.png)
5. Save and close.
6. Restart the cmd / system .
7. [Run go in the cmd to check the working .](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4N756.png)

Answer (score 1):

If you are not able to solve the problem even after adding environment variables, you can check if you have installed Go extension from VSCode, install it if you haven't already. Then, when you create a new GO file to work in the working directory, "gopls command not available" will be popped up,click install all to get full support inside VSCode.
I solved the issue like this, I hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

There could be possibility that you have not installed the correct exe folder. for windows download the windows-Version.msi, In my case i previously installed amd processor exe file. hence it was not running.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You need to set path var like from `C:\Users\YourUser\go` to `C:\Users\YourUser\` then you can see your go version in your command line `go version`